# Shared lazy coroutine / memoized coroutine execution

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Context:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope

data class DatabaseData(
    val a: String,
    val b: String
)

interface DatabaseFetcher {
    suspend fun get(): DatabaseData
}

class MyClass(
    private val databaseFetcher: DatabaseFetcher
) {
    suspend fun a() = coroutineScope {
        val a = async { databaseFetcher.get().a }
        //imagine more async{}'s here
        a //imagine a gets computed in regards to the other async{}'s as well
    }

    suspend fun b() = databaseFetcher.get().b
}

class MyController(private val databaseFetcher: DatabaseFetcher) {
    suspend fun someFun() = coroutineScope {
        // the reduced example doesn't need a coroutineScope of course, imagine some async{} here
        MyClass(databaseFetcher)
    }
}
```

I am trying to call `databaseFetcher.get()` only once if either `a()` or `b()` are called on `MyClass`. Basically a lazy future that gets started when either `a()` or `b()` is called, but with coroutines.

What I have tried so far:

- Can't use `by lazy{}` as the `coroutineScope` matters here and I can't use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` as I use a custom Context (multithreading, Spring request scoped data etc.) - passing my context in here seems awkward (would it be bad practice?)
- I can't pass an `async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY)` when constructing `MyClass` as it would block indefinitely if the `Deferred<T>` is never `await()`ed on, which may happen when neither `a()` or `b()` is called. It also blocks indefinitely because the corresponding `coroutineScope` is constructed when `MyClass` is constructed which would block as `a()` and `b()` are called later after `MyClass` has been fully constructed because (as I understand) a `coroutineScope` is only unblocked when all its children are done, which doesn't hold true for a lazy async thats awaited outside the curent scope
- Using a wider coroutine context may leak when the lazy async is never awaited - is this true? I couldn't find much about this

This is being done in the context of GraphQL wherein either `a` `b` or both can be selected. There are boilerplatey solutions to this but as I am still learning about coroutines I wondered if there is an elegant solution to this which I don't see yet. The `CoroutineStart.LAZY` issue really caught me by surprise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this:

```kotlin
fun <T : () -> U, U> T.memoized(): suspend () -> Deferred<U> {
    val self = this
    val deferred: CompletableDeferred<U> = CompletableDeferred()
    val started = AtomicBoolean(false)
    return suspend {
        if (started.compareAndExchange(false, true)) {
            deferred
        } else {
            coroutineScope {
                async {
                    deferred.complete(self())
                    deferred.await()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any `() -> T` function (basically any function with captured arguments) can be `.memoized()`. Whatever callee first calls the returned `suspend fun` will be used to start the `Deferred<U>` while allowing said callee to block whenever he sees fit:

```kotlin
val expensive = { someExpensiveFun(param, param2 }.memoize();
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // or some other context
    val a = expensive()
    val b = expensive()

    a.await()
    b.await()
}
```